# WholeRowIterator and a Range with one of one key

Tags: accumulo

I am having a problem with Accumulo 1.5.1  involving the WholeRowIterator and getting the filter to return rows when the range is specified over one key.

```
Range testRange = new Range("aa", true, "aa\0", false);
```

When I set this range to a scanner with an associated WholeRowIterator, the filter does not return the specified row "aa" to the client even though the overridden filter function is returning true for this range.

Is the range malformed for a scanner using WholeRowIterator?  What would be a correct range?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging around I was able to find this post:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/accumulo-user/201207.mbox/%3CCAPMpPc5v83wn_PTqh-Hh1-TfP-PxLELwPQsDHkCKK_KzR3yqUg@mail.gmail.com%3E

A WholeRowIterator needs to have its priority set to 21 or greater to not have conflicting behavior with Version iterators.

This was an annoying bug because it provided many false positives in testing.

Answer (score 1):

The `Range` you specified should be correct. You can also try using the [`new Range(CharSequence)`](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.5/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/data/Range.html#Range%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) constructor for simplicity.

Verify that your data is shaped how you think it is - you could have visibilities getting in the way or something else. Go to the shell and do a `scan -t [table] -r aa` and make sure that you get results.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I verified that a scan over a range of +/- infinity works to return this value using the WholeRowIterator but when the range is reduced to this one key, the key is not returned. This key is the first key on the tablet.